# Ubuntu 16.04 running very poorly on full install on flash drive even though it ran well on Virtual Box

Tags: usb-drive, performance

I tried Ubuntu on virtual box for some time with mostly good performance. However after installing Ubuntu onto a 16 GB USB with a 32GB one for storage and trying to run it on the same computer it runs extremely slowly and programs often stop responding.

Why after ubuntu was running well in virtual box is it running slow after installing it on the computer? (This should in theory make it run better since it has direct access to the hardware)

system has:

- 4gb of ram
- Intel HD 3000 graphics
- Intel® Core™ i5-2410M CPU @ 2.30GHz × 4

Ubuntu 16.04 64-bit is installed on a 16GB pny flash drive

Comment: What's the read and write access speed of the USB drive(s) in question? You can measure it with Gnome Disks.

Comment: Install Ubuntu into a *fast USB 3 pendrive*, and it will perform much better. See these links and links from them, https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick#Notes_about_speed and http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2230389

Answer (score 3):

#### Running slow because of low USB throughput

When running Ubuntu from a USB-Stick and starting programs or loading data, the throughput of your USB-Stick will be a bottleneck. This is why you experience low performance although Ubuntu now has direct hardware access. The access time of your hard drive / SSD is significantly faster than USB throughput.

#### Install onto new partition for increased performance

To get good performance (comparable / probably faster than Virtual Box), create a new partition on your hard drive and install Ubuntu there. You will require about 5 GB of space minimum.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect it may be due to it running from a USB stick. Why not install on its own partition ?